# Rails remote call not working / javascript format

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ajax

bit new to Ajax and rails.

I have a link on an image that when clicked should replace the image.

Here's my link in the view:

```
<div id="flag_<%= message.id %>">
  <%= link_to image_tag("white_star.png"), flag_message_path(message), remote: true %>
</div>
```

this calls flag method on messages controller. For format.js i have flag.js:

```
{$('#flag_<%=@message.id%>').html('<% if @message.flag == false %><a href="/messages/96/flag" data-remote="true"><img alt="White_star" src="/assets/white_star.png" title="flag"></a>
    <% else %>
    <a href="/messages/96/flag" data-remote="true"><img alt="Red_star" src="/assets/red_star.png" title="flag"></a>
    <% end %>');
}
```

this returns to the browser:

```
{
$('#flag_94').html('<a href="/messages/96/flag" data-remote="true"><img alt="White_star" src="/assets/white_star.png" title="flag"></a>
');
}
```

which seems ok to me, yet nothing happens.... Any thoughts??
thanks

Comment: was wondering if it is anything to do with the quotation marks, but can't get it right

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Everything seems ok, but I would drop the surrounding accolades in your `format.js.erb`. Those are not needed.

If there is an error in your javascript, you should see it in the javascript console.

It is generally good practice to extract code like this into a partial.

So you would have a `replace_image.html.erb` :

```
<% if @message.flag == false %>
  <a href="/messages/96/flag" data-remote="true"><img alt="White_star" src="/assets/white_star.png" title="flag"></a>
<% else %>
  <a href="/messages/96/flag" data-remote="true"><img alt="Red_star" src="/assets/red_star.png" title="flag"></a>
<% end %>
```

and in your `format.js.erb` you would just do

```
$('#flag_<%=@message.id%>').html("<%= escape_javascript(render :partial => 'replace_image') %>");
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks!! escaping seems to have done the trick, also had some \n floating in there.